# Is it possible to remove the 'install4j' text from the License agreement window

Tags: install4j

Install4j gives you the option to include a license agreement window during an install.  Unfortunately the line above the Next, Cancel buttons has the word 'install4j' prefixed to it.  Is there any way to remove this?   (Note: The Destination window seems to do the same thing.  So really is there anyway to remove this line prefix from all of the windows that have it?)

Answer (score 6):

Go to Installer->Screens & Actions and select the installer.

Then you can either disable the "Add install4j watermark to installer screens" property or fill in the "Custom watermark text" property.

Comment: Still there exists references to install4j in other places. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: You can override all messages on the General Settings->Languages step.

Comment: Eh... i do not see any of the strings listed there. am i supposed to know how to make a customization localization file?

Comment: OH i see from this subtle comment under the "custom localization file" `you can override the default message in the $INSTALL4J_HOME/resource/messages directory`

Comment: ah no even better, create a custom language file using the new button. then hit "override message" and then you'll see the keys listed there.